# Align div horizontally with CSS3

Tags: css, html, alignment

this is my code. I made those divs as table cell

```
<div class="logo">
text
</div>

<div class="stats" >
text
</div>
```

and my css

```
.logo
{
    display:table-cell;
    width:420px;
}

.stats
{
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow align first div to the left and second one to the right without using float?
Or just to align content inside them to the left and right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are much cleaner ways to go about this than using obscure display methods like table-cell - usually you can accomplish what you want with `block`, `inline`, or `inline-block`. What are you doing that requires table-cell?

That being said, there's a few things you can do. To align text or inline content inside those elements, it's just `text-align` - `left` or `right`. If you're nesting divs, you can apply a rule like `.logo *{ float: left; }`.

I'm unfamiliar with the dynamics of table cell display, but if you want to position without using float, usually you do `position: absolute;` along with `left: 0px;` and `right: 0px;`. This has its own set of problems though.

Answer (score 1):

On a different note, You could use padding with float to create a pseudo effect of a table, and "padding + margin + constraint div" prove to be the best alignment attributes for me... Though this may not solve your "without float" problem.